# How to show menu on click rather than mouse hover with jquery and css?

Tags: jquery

https://universaltechnologiescorp.com is my website. There is categories menu on left (product models) set as open on mouse hover and close. I want it to open on mouse click..

I built on jquery but it does not work..Can any one help to sort this out?

Thanks

Comment: To provide that example, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach is to set the navigation links as active on the click of the li and have a nested ul of the sub-navigation  content below and only show this ul in the active li.

The jquery is then only used to toggle the active state of the li's and isn't even needed for that - plain js could do that.

You could jazz it up with some fancy css3 animations as well - instead of just toggling the diplay state. Note that i built this to demonstrate the concept - it, rather than trying to get your nav structure and modify it.

```js
$('.navigation li').click(function(){
  $('.navigation li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active')
 })
```

```css
.navigation {list-style: none;margin-left:0;padding-left:0;}
.navigation > li a {font-size: 1.2em; margin-bottom: 15px; cursor:pointer}
.navigation > li ul {display:none}
.navigation > li.active ul {display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul  class="navigation">
    <li class="active">
      <a>Option 1</a>
      <ul class="sub-navigation">
        <li>option 1a</li>
        <li>option 1b</li>
        <li>option 1c</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Option 2</a>
      <ul class="sub-navigation">
        <li>option 2a</li>
        <li>option 2b</li>
        <li>option 2c</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Option 3</a>
      <ul class="sub-navigation">
        <li>option 3a</li>
        <li>option 3b</li>
        <li>option 3c</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```